# How to submit the child form from parent form submit button

Tags: angular6, angular7, angular4-forms

Can you please suggest me how to submit the child form from parent form submit button

```
<form #parentForm="ngForm">

  <form #childForm="ngForm">

    <input type="text" #textBox1="ngModel" required/>

    <h1 *ngIf="childForm.submitted && textBox1.inValid">
       Error Validation
    </h1>

  </form>

  <button type="submit">Submit!!</button>

</form>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try [FormGroup](https://www.concretepage.com/angular-2/angular-2-formgroup-example)

Some of features are:- 
**FormControl**:It is a class that tracks the value and validation state of a form control. 
**FormGroup**: It is a class that tracks the value and validity state of a group of FormControl. 
**FormArray**: It is a class that tracks the value and validity state of array of FormControl, FormGroup and FormArray.
**FormControlName**: It is a directive that syncs a FormControl in an existing FormGroup to a form control by name. 
**FormGroupDirective**: It is a directive that binds an existing FormGroup to a DOM element. 
**FormGroupName**: It is a directive that syncs a nested FormGroup to a DOM element. 
**FormArrayName**: It is a directive that syncs a nested FormArray to a DOM element.